# Nintendo Switch on HDMI Switcher

Tags: nintendo-switch

I have a NintendoSwitch on an HDMI switcher with other things (WiiU, Playstation, etc.)

It's annoying because sometimes, the Switch, when docked, will 'ping' the HDMI Switcher, switching the HDMI ouput to the switch while you are in a epic MGS5 fight.

Is there a way to stop it from doing that? Right now our solution is to leave it out of the dock, but that makes it out of battery when we want to go out with it.

So is there a way to prevent that HDMI Ping while the Switch is docked?

Comment: What is the deal with this HDMI pinging I keep hearing about?  I've heard some other people having problems with it doing something similar without a HDMI switcher.

Comment: Looks like it may be a TV issue.  One [support page](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/social/questions/detail/qid/48818/~/sleeping-switch-auto-switches-hdmi-input-on-samsung-smarttv/session/L3F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDk4MjQwNDA5L3NpZC9mVU0yS2xuTmFBUEFmOWRkR0wwTUx6aVFTNzBBMnVVbGJnYjBYUFhISl9FNEVmblZxTlU5a0xtV3RkUjFvalQ0SzBTc2t1bVV5OU5xSF9mVzRTemY2SmZKcUltWEE1T0VPdVd6QkI5djk4ZG9CRlkzMVNNM0t3aGclMjElMjE=) showed it was a Samsung issue.  Also, updating the switch may resolve it.

Comment: Yeah it's a Samsung Issue, but the switcher is out of the TV, not the in TV like samsung.

Comment: The 3.0.0 patch was supposed to address this. So far, it hasn't swtiched on me as far as I could tell. And it's not a TV problem, it's the Nintendo Switch and it's bad implementation of the [HDMI-CEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control) spec. I use an external HDMI switcher and before, the Nintendo Switch would occasionally switch if I'm using a different device.

Comment: Ah ok I haven't jumped to 3.0.0 yet, I'll try and see.

Comment: @Fredy31 Did 3.0 fix it for you?

Comment: Gave it a few days, it's not a constant problem. Some nights it sempt to be every 10 min, some nights it never did it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 3.0.0 Update should solve this, released June 19th 2017

> Improvements to prevent unintended HDMI input change with certain TVs while the console is docked in Sleep Mode

[Release Notes](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22525/p/897)

Comment: Yup, seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: This jumped back at the top of my list. Can still confirm. An update solved the problem.